# Help needed finding laptop FFC keyboard connector

Tags: connector, identification, computers, keyboard, buying

I have a Thinkpad T440 keyboard that I'd like to convert to a USB keyboard. I've been looking for an FFC connector for it and it's been difficult finding it. It has 32 pins and 0.5mm pin pitch. The problem is that the cable is not straight, it has notches at the end (not tabs). Also, the notch on one side is 1mm deep and on the other side only about 0.6mm:

[image: Flat flex cable]

Here are a couple of images of the board connector, from an [iFixit guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Lenovo+Thinkpad+T440+laptop+Keyboard+Replacement/105891):

- https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/SRVjdRpMgGfAyEAP.huge
- https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/sTQR3J2d2XNhXos5.huge

In the schematic the connector shows up as `JAE_FL10S032HA1`, but I haven't been able to find anything about it, except for Lenovo schematic references. I haven't found any 32 pin FFC connectors from JAE.

I was able to find some connectors that look promising, from Aces, with the 1mm deep notch on one side and 0.6mm deep notch on the other, but I can't find any place to buy them:

- http://www.acesconn.com/series/51699-xxxxx-xxx/2216
- http://www.acesconn.com/series/51580-xxxxx-xxx/2199
- http://www.acesconn.com/series/51555-xxxxx-xxx/2193

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: This is not necessarily shopping related, I would like to identify this connector. I'm not sure if it's really an Aces connector, or I would at least like an alternative.

Comment: Well, the schematic name for the original connector looks similar to JAE's connectors like "FA5S030HP1" from the "FA5" series. Maybe "FL10" is custom or out of catalogue series with the "L" standing for "Locking" or even "Lenovo" (who knows).